# Laravel includes hidden attributes in json using DB class

Tags: json, laravel-4, fluent

I have declared some hidden fields in model to prevent them from getting included in json output. Eloquent is working fine. But I have to build queries based on url parameters , So I am using DB class for it.

But It returns all the fields of database table. So is there any way to use that hidden attributes with DB class?

What I did for now that I used visible array in Models rather than using hidden; and passed it to addSelect method.

It seems fine to me. But I want to know if there any method to take hidden attributes into account while using DB class

Comment: Can you give an example of a query you are building, it may be possible to do it with Eloquent.

Comment: @RMcLeod Actually I am building query dynamically based on api url parameters. and I think Eloquent is not as flexible as DB in building queries in loops and switches adding where clause and other sql clauses. And what if any query isn't possible with Eloquent,  then ultimately I will have to use DB again

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to exclude certain columns while building your query using QueryBuilder, because there is no *easy* way to exclude columns using SELECT query. Your best bet will be to use the visible array, or manipulate the results to exclude the hidden fields.